# Count the occurrence of a text in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of occurrence of a specific word in my data frame.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Text = "The Covid-19 pandemic is no doubt disrupting the economy and the quality of 
life. And despite the governments efforts to ensure the survival of the economy, the recent resurgence 
of Covid-19 cases has brought most of the of hotels in the country to their knees."), row.names = 
c(NA,-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to count the word "COVID". I changed all the text to uppercase
`text2<- toupper(df)` and tried this code to count the occurrence of the word "COVID"
`text_count <- length(grep("COVID", text2))` , but the result I got was 1, but my desire result is 2.

Comment: `stringr::str_count(text2, 'COVID')`

Comment: `grep` returns presence on a whole string at a time, not on substrings.